# Illustrator color picker fails to detect a web color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, svg, web-safe

I opened a new document in Adobe Illustrator CS5, which defaults to CMYK as a color mode. I imported a raster image, used LiveTrace  with 6 grayscale colors, expanded, and saved as SVG, which changed the color mode to RGB (which I believe makes no difference, since it's only grayscale colors at this point). In the text, I replaced black in the plain text of the SVG to one [web color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names) and gray with a tint of that web color, where the opacity is proportional to the amount of gray. In the example below, I used `7B68EE` for `MediumSlateBlue`. I opened the SVG file in Illustrator and the color picker shows `6666FF` instead of `7B68EE`; when I click `OK`, the color changes to `6666FF`.

Here is the color picker pointed at the area with `7B68EE` in the source SVG file:

[image: Color picker on 7B68EE color showing 6666FF]

And here are three images of the difference for this case. The SVG with `fill="#7B68EE"` in the plain text:

[image: Design with tints of 6666FF in an RGB document]

The same SVG after clicking OK in the color picker for color `7B68EE`, which becomes `6666FF`:

[image: Design after clicking OK in color picker]

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and Illustrator CS5 15.1.0 (yes, I really am, I was able to make them play nicely).

Why does the Illustrator color picker show a web color such as `MediumSlateBlue (7B68EE)` as `6666FF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the 'Only Web Colors' option checked, the panel will approximate whatever value from the picker to a predefined list of web-safe colors: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-colors.html

So, just ***uncheck*** the 'Only Web Colors'.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Lucian's accepted answer: a web color is different from a web-safe color. `MediumSlateBlue` is `7B 68 EE` and [web-safe colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_colors#Color_table) only use doubled characters in multiples of 3 (`00`, `33`, `66`, `99`, `CC`, and `FF`). For Illustrator, "web color" means "web-safe".

Similarly, if you are in CMYK color mode, the color picker will approximate your web colors without telling you. For example, make a rectangle with `#800000`, double-click on the foreground color to go to the color picker, quit the dialog, and double-click again on the foreground color. The dialog shows `#800000` the first time and `#7F1416` the second time. Illustrator approximates `#800000`, which is not in the CMYK gamut, to one that is. See [Why does Adobe Illustrator change my web colors?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132032/why-does-adobe-illustrator-change-my-web-colors) .